# Google Sheet: How to set auto increment number when skipping in-between merged cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

currently, I am manually giving all numbers by skipping the middle title row.

is there any way I can assign an auto increment number if added new row is in any section?

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

use in A5:

```
=INDEX(IF(B5:B="",,COUNTIFS(B5:B, "<>", ROW(B5:B), "<="&ROW(B5:B))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden column with the last number and a formula to increment it in column A.
Let's choose column C to be hidden.
In A5, use this:

```
=IF(B5="",,C4+1)
```

In C5, use:

```
=IF(A5="",C4,A5)
```

Copy those cells to the rest of their columns.
If any text is included in column B (starting from B5), the next number appears in column A. Column C repeats the new number if it appears, or the number of above (to be used as reference for column A in next row).

The result is like that:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| 1 | d | 1 |
|  |  | 1 |
| 2 | bv | 2 |
| 3 | bg | 3 |
| 4 | asd | 4 |
|  |  | 4 |
| 5 | vf | 5 |
|  |  | 5 |
|  |  | 5 |
|  |  | 5 |
|  |  | 5 |
|  |  | 5 |
|  |  | 5 |

Select column C and the option "Hide column" to don't be bothered by this column. If you need to make it visible again, click on one of the arrows that appear between columns B and D.
The final result is like that:

| A | B | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | d |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | bv |  |  |  |
| 3 | bg |  |  |  |
| 4 | asd |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | vf |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

See example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_IR0YOCpis6Yn_UrO9y_bx02haRQnEgrMhJl0QAltts